# Force QTimer() timeout in PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a pySide application which uses  QTimer to refresh its status once a minute. In some cases I need to force an immediate update, and then restart the timer

```
self.timer = QTimer()
self.timer.timeout.connect(self._update_status)
self.timer.start(60 * 1000)
```

Is there any way to force the timer to expire and emit the timeout signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution seems to be simply this:

```
        self.timer.start() # restart the timer
        self.timer.timeout.emit() # force an immediate update
```

It is also possible to force an immediate update by calling `setInterval(1)`, but this has the disadvantage that you would then need to reset the timer interval *again* in the slot connected to the signal:

```
        self.timer.setInterval(1) # force an immediate update

    def _update_status(self):
        ...
        if self.timer.interval() == 1:
            self.timer.setInterval(60 * 1000) # reset the interval
```

(Note that if an interval of *zero* is used, Qt will only emit the timeout signal once the event queue has been cleared. So, strictly speaking, `setInterval(0)` wouldn't necessarily force an *immediate* update).

Comment: Your first suggestion to use timeout.emit() worked great and it's simple. tnx.